# html5 video tag not playing on chrome using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to download an mp4 video file in PHP. the file generated successfully with the code below.

```
$result_ad // is the PHP variable contains video content.

header("Content-Type: video/mp4");  
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($result_ad));

echo $result_ad;exit;
```

It generate an html5 video and successfully played it on Mozilla.

But not playing on google Chrome.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @natanel97 nothing error. not playing. no error. the player is loaded but video not playing

Comment: can we see the html?

Comment: Are you sure your video file is mp4. And if so, are you sure format is correct. Here are supported formats for chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats